# Android TCP multicast missing message

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-asynctask

I build a TCP multicast chat application using asynctask.
I am also trying to order the message in FIFO and causal order.

However, when I try to send a lot of messages simultaneously for testing, it misses some messages but I can't find the reason.
I have tried as hard as I can to improve the performance of the program because I thought the performance could be the reason. but still having the same issue. 
I attached some important part of my code.
Most of all,

```
    private class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<ServerSocket, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ServerSocket... sockets){
        ServerSocket serverSocket = sockets[0];
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            while(true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream inputstream = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputstream));

                String msg = ""+in.readUTF();
                String time = ""+in.readUTF();

                String temp = time+"||"+msg;
                publishProgress(temp);
                in.close();


            }} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                socket.close();
                serverSocket.close();////
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here is onProgressUpdate.

```
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String...strings) {
        /*
         * The following code displays what is received in doInBackground().
         */
        String strReceived = strings[0].trim();
        TextView remoteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        remoteTextView.append(strReceived + "\t\n");
        try {
            sequencer(strReceived);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return;
    }
}
```

..

```
   private class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... msgs) {

        Date currentDate= new Date();
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime());
        Message temp = new Message(myPort, msgs[0], time);////
        try {

            for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                        Integer.parseInt(REMOTE_PORTS[i])), 1000);
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream));

                o.writeUTF(msgs[0]);
                o.writeUTF(""+time);
                o.flush();////
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask UnknownHostException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask socket IOException");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Can you find the part causes the problem?

Comment: I had to use TCP because this is assignment I got from school...

Comment: You're not doin multicast here, you doing point-to-point TCP with multiple targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequencing / Queueing /Acknowledgement all these things are part of TCP so it is done by the protocol itself so you do not need to do all those explicitly from your code. There are still some parts of your code that can be improved. Like:

```
    String time = received.split("\\|\\|")[0];
String msgToSend = received.split("\\|\\|")[1];
//Instead of doing this, its better to do this: 
String peices[]=received.split("\\|\\|");
String msgToSend=peices[1];
String time=peices[0]
```

Also you can check if you are receiving all the raw messages and if its during the parsing process the messages are getting lost using a log:

```
    Log.d("RAW_MESSAGE","Message Received: "+temp); //in your doInBackground
```

If you get all the messages that you send in this log, then there is nothing wrong with the protocol or the sending/receiving process rather there is a problem while you are processing the message. Also for these types of use-cases, try using the Service component rather than AsyncTask.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you think I have to implement something like hold-back queue for servertask to prevent from skipping to receive some messages?

Comment: No no. If you're using TCP, none of these are required. Instead of entering message in a textview, I'd rather put them in a list view.  That way, you'll not loose any message and you can scroll through them.

Comment: The reason I am sequencing and queueing messages is because this application is not just for 1:1 communication. Each device will receive messages from other devices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all multicast is over UDP, not TCP.

And if you want to create a multicast app, you should use multicastsocket

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html